# Fork-like function for Conduit

Tags: haskell, fork, consumer, conduit, sink

I want calculating hash of http post body and parsing it simultaneously when receiving, so I need a function like this:

```
unionSinks :: Monad m => Consumer a m r1 -> Consumer a m r2 -> Consumer a m (r1, r2)
unionSinks = ...

sinkBody :: Monad m => FromJSON v => Consumer ByteString m (Digest SHA1, v)
sinkBody = sinkHash `unionSinks` sinkParser json
```

When I developed image uploading I used `passthroughSink` in similar way. But I don't needed the result of conduit, which saves image to file, in this case.

Generally, I know how to implement fork using MVar-like things, but I don't sure that this is optimal solution.

Comment: I'm not sure I completely understand the question, but have you checked out 'ZipConduit' and more specifically 'ZipSink' (in Data.Conduit)?

Comment: I need the same input data for both consumers. Additionally I need values, which returned from both.

Comment: Hmm, It seems this is what I need. I didn't carefully read the docs. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Indeed you need [`ZipSink`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-1.2.5/docs/Data-Conduit.html#t:ZipSink) (or more general `ZipConduit`):

```
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Conduit

unionSinks :: (Monad m) => Sink a m r1 -> Sink a m r2 -> Sink a m (r1, r2)
unionSinks s1 s2 = getZipSink ((,) <$> ZipSink s1 <*> ZipSink s2)
```